# Как написать регулярное выражение, которое работает с многострочным текстом?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Есть список вывода в переменную вида:

```
ONLINE Yes
ONLINE Yes
ONLINE Yes
```

Нужно в баше в "если" запихать сверку на регулярном выражении, что вся переменная состоит только из таких строчек.

У меня получилось так: `^(ONLINE Yes($|\n))*$`, на сайтике работает с `^` (начать сначала), а в баше не хочет:

```bash
if [[ "${V_CELL_DISK}" =~ ^(ONLINE Yes($|\n))*$ ]];
    then
    ...
fi
```

Глянуть можно тут https://regex101.com/r/75lrTP/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайте вы проверяете регулярное выражение в соответствии со стандартом [PCRE2](https://www.pcre.org/), в Perl ваше регулярное выражение прекрасно работает, а в Bash `\n` не будет работать, используйте `$'\n'` вместо `\n`.

Например, так:

```regex
^(ONLINE Yes($|$'\n'))*$
```

Comment: премного благодарен

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в \n - пришлось выносить в переменную :(

Comment: Опишите решение более подробно.